# having trouble by using a collection as an asset, including an empty

Tags: shader-nodes, asset-browser

i have a collection/ texture, where i adjust a setting in the shader with an empty (in this case the colors of an array)
every time i set both into one collection, mark them together as an asset, i got two problems:

- first, i can't edit the object neither the empty (sure via right click- adjust, but it doesnt work with the colors)
- once i place it out of the asset browser, i get a second empty which sets its origin at the world center

so how can I get an collection, which is still adjustable, and get rid of the second empty?
( i want multiple similar objects in the asset-file,  so its not an option just leave that one object in the center of the original file)

if you look at the pictue, the left one is the original object, 3D cursor is at center of the world and the right on is what i get from dragging it from the assetbrowser.

[image: My problem]

Answer (score 0):

The collection is linked, which means that the data inside the collection  cannot be edited by default. To edit the data-blocks, you can click on the empty, press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and select "Make Instances Real". Note that this removes the collection, so you will have to create a new collection and manually put the data-blocks back into it. I hope this helps!